# The closure of span of a linearly independent and convergent sequence in $\ell^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^2$ be a sequence in $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent and $v_n \to v_0$.

I would like to know if exist a subsequence $\{v_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for each fixed $p \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
v_{n_p}
\notin
\overline{span}
\{v_{n_k}\}_{k > p}
$$

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is still obviously "no", e.g. fix $v_0 \neq 0$ and let $v_n = (1 - 1/n)v_0$.

Comment: Better on MathStackExchange

Comment: The question now seems reasonable. Voting to reopen.

Comment: ok thanks @NikWeaver it was just a missing assumption, an involuntary error

Comment: the assumption that $v_n\to 0$ does not contibute to anything, it seems.  The span does not depend on the norm of the generating vecotrs.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the answer is "no" if the sequence is constant. Did you mean to put some other assumptions?

Comment: thanks for your comment, now i edit and add other assumption